# How do I display a topic at the top of the messages in a google group?

Tags: google-groups

How do I display a topic at the top of the messages in a google group?

The action menu used to include an item for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2023, according to [What's new in Groups](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/9718200?hl=en) **Pinning topics** (Making conversations appear at the top of the list) was deprecated.